# How to fix? Sound Juicer [...] Cannot access CD: The name :1.36 was not provided by any .service files

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10, cd, sound-juicer, musicbrainz

I copied a CD's tracks to an external hard drive after inputting [the info into the musicbrainz database](https://musicbrainz.org/release/642610db-b5c7-4f15-a6f8-007bcf0d8ce3?artist=). Inserting the second disc of this 5-CD set, I encounter the error as shown in the screenshot:

> Could not read the CD
>
> Sound Juicer could not read the track listing on this CD.
>   Reason: Cannot access CD: The name :1.36 was not provided by any .service files

How do I solve this problem? (I don't understand this error message.)

[image: screenshot of Sound Juicer error message]

Comment: Strange that accessing cdda://sr0/ in Thunar still works (gives list of .wav's).  So as a workaround you could copy them using Thunar and convert them.  Not a solution though if one wants to use SJ to link CD ToC....

Answer (score 0):

Any question marks, double quotes, or colons in CD title or Song title can cause Sound Juicer problems and give a vague message that it cannot copy this CD, or song.  Need to edit out the above by hand then start extraction again.